# strip part of a filename with jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code below to send an ID to my page:

The image names will always look like this
12.jpg
12-1.jpg
12-2.jpg 
12-3.jpg e.t.c

I need to alter the line below so it will only send the 12 not the -1,-2,-3 e.t.c My code below already removes the .jpg part

```
var id = $(this).attr('src').split('/').pop().replace('.jpg','');
```

Comment: Is there a way of adding a wild card in here?

Answer (score 0):

Remove trailing hyphen separated parts:

```
id= id.split('-')[0]
```

Comment: Hopefully there's no other dashes allowed in the filename :)

Comment: I added your example like so 

     var id = $(this).attr('src').split('/').pop().replace('.jpg','');
  id = id.split('-')[0];

was that right?

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = $(this).attr('src').split('/').pop().replace('.jpg','');
var hyphenIndex = id.indexOf('-');
id = hyphenIndex > 0 ? id.substring(0, hyphenIndex) : id;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a regex instead?

```
var id = $(this).attr('src').replace( /(-\d+)?\.jpg/, '' );
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? It works for me. I should have put a `\` before the `.` in `.jpg`, maybe that will help.

Comment: Err, that's a '\' before the . in .jpg. Also if your filename is .jpeg of course this wont work so you could do: jpe?g

Answer (score 0):

like bobince, this should work...

```
var id = $(this).attr('src').split('/').pop().split('-')[0].replace('.jpg','');
```